# How can I fetch all failed jobs as list and show in custom message?

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow named `Security` with three jobs. The last job take care of sending notifications to slack about failed jobs. This is my slack notification job:

```
  reportFailure:
    name: Slack notification
    needs: [ dependencies-vulnerabilities, image-vulnerabilities ]
    if: ${{ failure() }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Slack notification
        uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2
        env:
          SLACK_CHANNEL: my-channel
          SLACK_COLOR: '#ff0000'
          SLACK_ICON: https://library.kissclipart.com/20181123/hqe/kissclipart-mail-error-icon-clipart-computer-icons-email-0b0e6595c8731682.jpg
          SLACK_TITLE: ${{ github.repository }}
          SLACK_MESSAGE: "`${{ github.workflow }} / ${{ github.job }}` failed !!"
          SLACK_USERNAME: workflowBot
          MSG_MINIMAL: actions url,commit
          SLACK_FOOTER: ''
          SLACK_WEBHOOK: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK }}
```

This line `SLACK_MESSAGE: "${{ github.workflow }} / ${{ github.job }} failed !!"` shows me that `reportFailure` with this env `${{ github.job }}`.
How can I tell in `SLACK_MESSAGE` when one or all previous jobs failed and the name of the jobs? I want to show a list even if there is one or more jobs failed. Outcome should me something like:

`Workflow: Security | Jobs: dependencies-vulnerabilities, image-vulnerabilities failed!!` or if there is only one failed then:
`Workflow: Security | Jobs: image-vulnerabilities failed!!`

Thanks for help!

Comment: I think you're going to have to query the API, but I'm not sure if that information is already available _during_ the workflow run.

Comment: I would do this using artifacts to share `job_status` at the end of each job, and then create a last job that would gather all those informations to send them using SLACK. I've got an example of something similar [here (jobs 1 to 4)](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/16-conditional.yml), where you would need to create the SLACK message according to the job failures.